# Using parLapply with data.table's rbindlist causes CPU to go over 100%

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table, rbindlist

Consider the following code block:

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

random_function<-function(i){
  n<-1000000
  big_list<-list("vector")
  for (k in 1:100){
    big_list[[k]]<-data.table(rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
  }
  rbindlist(big_list,use.names = TRUE,fill=TRUE)
}


cl<-makeCluster(8)
clusterExport(cl,"random_function")
clusterCall(cl,function()library(data.table))
parLapply(cl,1:1000,random_function)
stopCluster(cl)
```

When I run it on my machine, which has 36 threads suddenly all the threads are being activated (i.e., the 8 ones which I specified when creating cluster exceed 100% load).

This only happens with data.table 1.12.0. Everything works perfectly with data.table_1.11.8. Is this a bug or I am just doing something wrongly? It seems that the problem is within rbindlist, i.e., if I do not put within a function rbindlist there is no more than 100% load on my 8 threads.[image]

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2 tools_3.5.2
```

Comment: is it better if you use `rbindlist(use.names = FALSE)`?

Comment: @jangorecki, just checked, using rbindlist(use.names = FALSE), does not solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see why calling rbindlist inside parLapply makes sense to even try. Are you trying to make rbindlist go faster? Or is the bigger picture that you parLapply something else compute intensive and it just happens to start with a rbindlist on each node?

Comment: When you write "everything went perfectly with 1.11.8" what precisely do you mean?  I understand that CPU did not go above 100% but we need to know more than that please. For example, what went perfectly that just using  a single call to rbindlist without using parLapply does not achieve?

Comment: @MattDowle yes, the bigger picture is as follows - I have 1000 folders, each containing 500 .csv files with names which I do not know ex ante. Then within parLapply I am reading all these files and then binding them together to create one file for each of 1000 folders. And there are other situations where (in my opinion) it makes sense to call rbindlist within parLapply.

Comment: @MattDowle CPU does not go above 100% using rbindlist on 1.11.8.

Comment: @Vitalijs Thanks for the extra information. What you've described is what databases are for.  Making data.table (or anything in R or Python) read 500,000 csv files (!) really fast and efficient is not a good idea!  Read these files into a database and then use the database.